# Android App development - Basic questions

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am an PHP developer. Today i tried to learn how to develop android app. I started with Hello World app.

It seems i have done something wrong. Whatever i type in the text box, I am getting only the "Hello World!" as the output in the next view.

views are written in the xml files and activities related to the views are in the java class.

```
sendMessage()
```

This function contains

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

1) What is EditText? In xml, I can see it is creating an text box to type. How does it work in the class file? and "R.id.edit_message" what value will be in it? Is it an object?

```
2) public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
```

I have no clue about the "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE"; MESSAGE. what is it? where is it coming from?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
    }
```

setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message); -> when should we call the setContentView?

At last, Why is it displaying always "Hello World!" all the time?

I know, It will be frustrating to see questions like this.
But I really need to start from the basic to understand the development.
Forgive me!

**CODES**

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfristapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfristapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

activity_display_message.xml
It is created automatically by eclispse. I didn't change it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" 
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you actually read the (very good) tutorial? It is all explained there. Start here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: Android development is Java with a fairly large UI and phone-related library; you would probably find a general introduction to Java (such as Head First) a helpful starting point before tackling a much more complex model.

Comment: Could you please paste all your code and pay attention to the formatting. It is easier to explain what the different elements are if we have the complete picture!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer your questions...**

`R.id.edit_message` is an integer, generated by Android, that references an id set in a layout file so, assuming your layout XML contains something like

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message" ... />
```

then `R.id.edit_message` is a identifier that tells Android, "when I'm using this layout and this id, I mean that particular EditText and no other".  The EditText is the box you type your message into.  Presumably, its contents are being read via editText.getText().toString() for being passed to the display activity.

`com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE` is just a name for a key.  When starting an activity, you can send it extra data in the form of key/value pair, e.g,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Your message")
startActivity(intent);
```

Declaring the key as a public static field means you can use the key in one activity, and then get the key name from another activity in order to retrieve the key, which is what

```
intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE)
```

is doing.

`setContentView` is used to tell the activity which layout file it should use*, and should be called in onCreate before any code that needs to access those views to, e.g, read the contents of your EditText, or add click handlers to buttons or so on.

---

*Actually, it doesn't have to be a reference to a layout file.  You could be creating your own view(s) first, in which case it would need to be called *after* all your views had been created.

---

**To answer your problem...**

In your display activity, you're creating a new TextView object and setting its message, but you don't add that view to the layout, so you never see it. Instead you are seeing the textview that is already there (which has the hello world message in it).  To change the message of the existing TextView in `activity_display_message.xml` give it an ID, e.g.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

and then do

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_message);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
```

to change its contents.  (If you really want to add a new textview, you will need to give the RelativeLayout in activity_display_message.xml an id, and then do something like

```
    // set the layout file:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // get a reference to the layout:
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.display_layout);

    // create your new textview:
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // set the TextView to display top left:
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    // add the view to layout:
    rl.addView(textView, params);
```

Comment: You're creating the TextView but not actually displaying it.  I've edited my original reply to hopefully explain further.

Answer (score 2):

post your full code xml and java file.

and about R.id.edit_message

when u put

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
....>

    </EditText>
```

in xml file it android generate one unique id for your control edit_message in R.java file
from where u can access the any control in your java file

so when u use R.id.edit_message it means you accessing the edit EditText from it int unique  id from R.java file in your java class.

Answer (score 0):

for your question #2:

your Constants will be saved in res/values/strings.xml. This is done because if you need to localize your app, you can just build another set of string.xml in another language. So if you assign a value for something like a TextView via your layout-xml-file, you can call it with

```
android:text="CONSTANT_NAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1) An EditText is simple a TextView that allows the user to modify its contents.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

In this class file this is basically a reference to the EditText created in XML so you can interact with it by changing it's contents or looking what the user typed.

```
R.id.edit_message
```

If you look in the xml it will be assigned an id usually like @+id/edit_message. This is how the code knows which view you want to attach to.

```
com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE
```

This is one way to reference the string passed in via the Intent.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
```

This should be called once you have finished constructing the view.

```
Why is it displaying always "Hello World!" all the time?
```

Because it sounds like you never change it. Have a look in the strings.xml file and change the value of "Hello World!", this will change the value in your application.

Comment: Yes, hello_world has the value of "Hello World!" in strings.xml. Should not it display what i type in the text box?

Comment: Without seeing a lot more code I can't really say. When the app starts it will likely display "Hello World!" and then you can edit the value in the box. Unless there is code to save what you type in then the next time you start the app it will say "Hello World!" again.

Comment: I have added the codes. TextView textView = new TextView(this);textView.setTextSize(40); textView.setText(message); I thought these lines will update the Hello World!

Comment: how do i debug what is passed in "message" variable?

Comment: Insert a break point after String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE); and inspect it.